# PowerShell form event triggered by another form event

Tags: powershell

I have created a form (in PowerShell Studio) and I am wondering if it is possible to see which event triggered another event? Example

```
$button1_Click = {
   $combobox1.Text = 'This is a test'
}
$combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {
   Write-Host "I was triggered by button1!" #Is this possible?
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The SelectedIndexChanged event fires whenever a new item is selected in the combobox. If you need to know somewhere in your code that a button was clicked I would suggest using a global semaphore variable that is set from within the Click event handler and checked in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler and reset after it is checked.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **EBGreen** for the helpful suggestion!

```
$button1_Click = {
    $global:buttonClicked = $true
    $combobox1.Text = 'This is a test'
}

$combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    If ($buttonClicked -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Host "I was triggered by button1!"
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "I was triggered by user action!"
    }
    $global:buttonClicked = $false
}
```